# How can i get account type using ContentResolver?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

How to retrieve account type (whatsapp,viber,etc..) using ContentResolver?
This is my code

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Log.d("log : ","name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                // get the phone number
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phone = pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String phone1 = pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    Log.d("log : ","phone" + phone + " type : "+phone1);
                }
                pCur.close();
```

Comment: What is `phone1` giving you?

Comment: phone1 give me type of phone number (work,home,etc..) but i want account type (whatsapp,viber,..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in Android's Contacts is split into 3 main tables:

1. `Contacts` - each entry represents one contact, and groups together one or more `RawContacts`
2. `RawContacts` - each entry represents data about a contact that was synced in by some `SyncAdapter` (e.g. Whatsapp, Google, Facebook, Viber), this groups multiple Data entries
3. `Data` - The actual data about a contact, emails, phones, etc. each line is a single piece of data that belongs to a single `RawContact`

The problem with your code is that you go over all `Contacts`, and then query for phones per contact. You're not querying the `RawContact` table which contains the `ACCOUNT_NAME` and `ACCOUNT_TYPE` you want. Plus, it's very inefficient to make hundreds of queries just to get all the phones on the device, you can do that with a single query instead.

```
// First create a mapping from RAW_CONTACT_ID to ACCOUNT_TYPE (e.g. Whatsapp)

Map<Long, String> rawContacts = new HashMap<Long, String>();
String[] projection1 = {RawContacts._ID, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE};
Cursor cur1 = cr.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection1, null, null, null);
while (cur1 != null && cur1.moveToNext()) {
    Long id = cur1.getLong(0);
    String account = cur1.getString(1);
    rawContacts.put(id, account);
}

// Now query for all the PHONES on the device (no need to query the Contacts table at all)

String[] projection2 = { Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID };
Cursor cur2 = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection2, null, null, null);

while (cur2 != null && cur2.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur2.getLong(0);
    String name = cur2.getString(1);
    String number = cur2.getString(2); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234
    int type = cur2.getInt(3); // a numeric value representing type: e.g. home / office / personal
    long raw = cur2.getLong(4);

    Log.d(TAG, "contact: " + id + ", name: " + name + ", number: " + number + ", type: " + type + ", raw-id: " + raw + ", account-type: " + rawContacts.get(raw));
}
```

**P.S.** 
you can create a second `HashMap` with `CONTACT_ID` as key to group all the info about a single contact per contact.